# Importing Python Module "Pulp" on Amazon AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pulp

I have been trying to import python module "Pulp" to the Amazon AWS Lambda but getting an error. Pulp is an optimization module which can be installed using pip ("pip install pulp") but as in AWS Lambda I'm not sure how to install it so I zipped everything along with Lambda Function from my local machine and uploaded it to AWS Lambda.

The error which I received:-

"Attempted relative import in non-package: ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 5, in lambda_handler
    import pulp
  File "/var/task/pulp.py", line 101, in 
    from .constants import *
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package"

Here is the link for .zip file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7SjHToKYgr3cXlHenpoOFljMDg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

On how to deploy to AWS lambda using virtualenv.

Comment: Hi Stuart Thanks for replying. The above issue got resolved but now I'm getting another error which is:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 40, in lambda_handler
    prob.solve()
  File "/var/task/Pulp1/pulp.py", line 1664, in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'

Comment: I think while on AWS Lambda it is not able to locate the solver

Comment: Did you install via virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I installed virtualenv on EC2, from there using Win SCP copied the pulp file then zipped it and uploaded to Lambda.

Comment: yeah looks like solver is None in this case you can Manually setup a path to cbc (copy the cbc.exe from the solver directory)

    `prob.solve(COIN_CMD(path="...put something here"))`

Comment: Hi Stuart, the issue got resolved earlier I was zipping the files using winrar which is on Windows but when I zipped file on cloud i.e Amazon Linux EC2 it worked. I don't know how that made difference but now it is working. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a standard Python error saying that it will only import things from the standard locations.  Since that includes the current directory you should be good but your code includes

```
    from . import pulp
```

when you have pulp.py in your directory. If pulp.py was all that was needed you would be fine.  But pulp.py wants to `import .constants`.  That **is** a relative reference which would be fine since it is supposed to be in a module.  In your case it is not fine.  If you want to keep going on this path you will have to go through and remove these relative imports.

Also your .zip file includes .pyc files.  Let these be generated on the target machine. Just send your .py's that they came from.