# Unable to access Python Pulp solver on AWS Lambda instance

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pulp

I'm trying to run an optimisation on AWS Lambda using Pulp in Python. I have packaged pulp (zipping the contents not the directory) along with my lambda_function and uploaded the zip. The error I'm stuck on is:

```
File "/var/task/pulp/pulp.py", line 1664, in solve
status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'
```

I've tried the fixes here:
[Importing Python Module "Pulp" on Amazon AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431487/importing-python-module-pulp-on-amazon-aws-lambda) in particular trying to specify the solver directly, and placing the solver (cbc) into the parent directory of the script to no avail. When I do try to specify the solver directly I get a different error:

```
Pulp: cannot execute cbc cwd: /var/task: PulpSolverError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 14, in lambda_handler
result = ip_optimise(recipes, settings)
File "/var/task/ip_optimise.py", line 102, in ip_optimise
prob.solve(COIN_CMD())
```

I've also tried putting in the path directly, eg:
`prob.solve(COIN_CMD("/var/task/cbc"))`
with the same error (cannot execute)

Answer (score 2):

I finally worked it out, it was a permissions problem on the solver (cbc). It may be related to the zipping process, I haven't got to the bottom of that yet, however I was able to get around the problem by copying the solver file (cbc) into /var/tmp (to allow access), then changing the permissions to be executable. The python code I used to do this is shown below:

```
# Copy solver to tmp
copyfile('pulp/solverdir/cbc/linux/64/cbc', '/tmp/cbc')
# Change permissions to executable
mode = os.stat('/tmp/cbc').st_mode
mode |= (mode & 0o444) >> 2    # copy R bits to X
os.chmod('/tmp/cbc', mode)   
# Solve using the newly located cbc solver
prob.solve(COIN_CMD(path="/tmp/cbc"))
```